# ASPxGridView on update can't find row cell template control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have the following code:

```
protected void gv_AfterPerformCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewAfterPerformCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CallbackName == "UPDATEEDIT")
    {
        ASPxGridView gv = (ASPxGridView)sender;
        GridViewDataColumn col = gv.Columns[0] as GridViewDataColumn;
        ASPxTextBox txt = gv.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(col, "test") as ASPxTextBox;
    }
}
```

In this code, `gv` is defined and it finds `col`. However, when running the `FindEditRowCellTemplateControl` part, it returns `null` for the textbox. The textbox definitely exists, I know this as this code used to work and hasn't been touched, but also if I change the `if` statement to look for `e.CallbackName == "CANCELEDIT"`, the code works as intended. There are other calls to other controls within this same block and none of them are returning valid controls.

The only thing that has changed between working code and not working, is that I changed the `BackColor` of another control in another column in the same grid. I have since changed it back as I wondered if this, inexplicably, was the issue.

What can have happened? Why would `txt` be `null` when `e.CallbackName == "UPDATEEDIT"` but is initialised correctly when `e.CallbackName == "CANCELEDIT"`?